# Divergence chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have two vector fields $f,g : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$. How do I calculate $\vec{\nabla} \cdot f(g(\vec{x}))$? Thank you very much!

Comment: But what happens if both components depend on both variables? I can't just exclude them from the divergence, right? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\eqalign{\vec{\nabla} \cdot f(g(\vec{x})) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f_1(g(\vec{x})) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f_2(g(\vec{x}))\cr
&= D_1(f_1)(g(\vec{x})) D_1(g_1)(\vec{x}) + D_2(f_1)(g(\vec{x}))D_1(g_2)(\vec{x}) +   D_1(f_2)(g(\vec{x})) D_2(g_1)(\vec{x}) + D_2(f_2)(g(\vec{x}))D_2(g_2)(\vec{x})}$$
where $D_i$ is derivative with respect to the $i$'th variable.